# maxfileCount not working in jQuery Upload File

Tags: jquery, cakephp, file-upload

Advanced tab : [Plugin Link](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)

i'm using latest file of jqueryUpload plugin, i want to set maximum 10 file limit here but **maxfileCount** is not working,

```
<link href="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/uploadfile.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://hayageek.github.io/jQuery-Upload-File/jquery.uploadfile.min.js"></script>
```

Html & jQuery code here..

```
<script>
$("#document").uploadFile({
    url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'evaults','action'=>'action', 'new')); ?>",
    multiple:true,
    dragDrop:true,
    showFileCounter:false,
    fileName:"doc",
    allowedTypes:"pdf,ppt,doc,docx,xls,xlsx",
    maxFileSize:5*1024*1024,
    autoSubmit:true,
    maxfileCount:10,
    formData: {filename:'doc'},
    showStatusAfterSuccess:false,
    dragDropStr:"<span id='comp_doc_name' style='color: #B2B2B2;font-size: 18px; opacity: 1; float:left'>Upload Company Document</span>",
    onSuccess: function (files, response, xhr)
    {
    }
  });
</script>
```

its allowing to upload more than 10 files..
is there any another parameter or anything missing in script??
Please help,  Thanks in advance :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by my self,

```
 $("#document").uploadFile({
        url:"<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'evaults','action'=>'action', 'new')); ?>",
        multiple:true,
        dragDrop:true,
        showFileCounter:false,
        fileName:"doc",
        allowedTypes:"pdf,ppt,doc,docx,xls,xlsx",
        maxFileSize:5*1024*1024,
        autoSubmit:true,
       // maxfileCount:10, <--- remove this
        formData: {filename:'doc'},
        showStatusAfterSuccess:false,
        dragDropStr:"<span id='comp_doc_name' style='color: #B2B2B2;font-size: 18px; opacity: 1; float:left'>Upload Company Document</span>",
        onSelect:function(files) {  
           var cnt = files.length;
           if(cnt <= 10)
           {
              return true; //to allow file submission.
           }
           else
           {

              return false;
           }
        },
        onSuccess: function (files, response, xhr)
        {
        }
      });
```

Can use **onSelect** method for file count and we can set file upload limit, MaxFileCount is not necessary now in this code.